# Call some plug-in/function inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

### The goal

Call Isotope inside an object.

### The problem

By Google Chrome: ***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope'.***

### The code

```
var mainResources = {
    // Execute this when the document is ready to go
    whenDocumentReady: function () {
        this.calculateResponsiveMeasures();

        jQuery("ul.products-list").isotope({
            itemSelector: "li",
            masonry: {
                gutterWidth: 15
            }
        });
    }
    [...]
}
```

I do not know what I have to do. By the way, thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: is your `isotope` library defined in the right place after jQuery is included?

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yes. Just to confirm, [look this image](http://i.imgur.com/WJ73jeS.jpg) (jQuery is the first)

Comment: @chiefGui, isotope is not jet defined. As @sushanth says. Or you misspelled it. E.g. `Isotope`

Comment: @Richard Thanks about your entry, but if I call the function in a `$(window).on("load", function() { ... })` it works fine. I guess the problem here is my object.

Comment: No, the problem here is the fact that your object is initialized, before isotope.. Just make sure you include the isotope.js file, before the file where your object is loaded.

Comment: You was right, @Richard. The **main.js** file was before **isotope.js**. Can you transform your comment into an answer to declare as resolved? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the fact that your object is initialized, before isotope.. Just make sure you include the isotope.js file, before the file where your object is loaded.